# Measuring rails json api with rack mini profiler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rack-mini-profiler

How do we get rack-mini-profiler to show in a rails json api? I believe this was asked here: [How to profile a rails controller that returns a json response with rack-mini-profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657334/how-to-profile-a-rails-controller-that-returns-a-json-response-with-rack-mini-pr) but the only answer is to try it out on an html file. How do we see the profiler measurements on a json page?

Comment: Rack-mini-profiler save the data when not displayed. Go to your profiled JSON page and then hit a HTML page, results shown will the the JSON page ones.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible yet. See: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/issues/243, which is an issue tracking it.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but I've noticed that when I test API requests originating from a rendered view, the profiler adds the API JSON to that page's JSON and shows all of it in the browser. I was able at some point to write a test that was checking the client side response time of some API calls, I only ditched it because Capybara gets flaky with complex DOM sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Rack Mini Profiler shows results by injecting its JavaScript on an HTML page.

So you will need to:

- hit that API endpoint (either in a browser or in the command line)
- go to a page that is rendered in HTML
- Look at the stack of results
- Pick the result that matches your API request

There you can look at SQL queries and all.